# Proving a recurrence relation by induction

Tags: math, recurrence, induction

I have a test coming up, and I need some help with a practise question... Need to prove this by induction:

---

Reccurence relation: m(i) = m(i-1) + m(i - 3) + 1, i >= 3
Initial conditions: m(0) = 1, m(1) = 2, m(2) = 3

Prove m(i) >= 2^(i/3)

---

Here is what I have been able to do so far:

**Base case:** m(3) >= 2 -----> 5 >= 2. Therefore it holds for the base case.

**Induction Hypothesis** Assume there is a k such that m(k) >= 2^(k/3) holds.

Now I must prove that it holds for k+1.

So we have:    m(k+1) >= 2^((k+1)/3)

which equals (by substituting hypothesis):

m(k) + m(k-2) + 1 >= 2^((k+1)/3)

This is where I am stuck. I'm not sure where to go from here. Any help will be appreciated. Thanks guys!

Comment: Try using _complete_ induction. ie. Suppose the inequality holds for all n <= k

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hints:

1. Prove that m(k) >= m(k-2).  (This is trivial.)
2. Since m(k+1) = m(k) + m(k-2) + 1, you can replace `=` with `>=` to get m(k+1) >= m(k) + m(k-2) + 1.
3. You can make substitutions on the right-hand side of `>=`, as long as what you put in is less than or equal to what you take out.  Start by using #1 to make a substitution in #2.

Comment: Thanks guys, I was able to figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

Consider your base case: you show that for 3 prior consecutive given values for m(0), m(1), and m(2), that the formula holds for m(4). Then show that m(k+1) formula works if you assume that it's true for 3 prior values m(k), m(k-1), and m(k-2) [this is valid for induction].

By initial condition

```
m(k+1) = m(k) + m(k-2) + 1
```

Substitution:

```
m(k+1) >= 2^(k/3) + 2^((k-2)/3) + 1
```

Factor the right hand side in terms of 2^((k+1)/3) [HINT: leave the +1 alone] and it should fall out from there.

Comment: Thanks guys, I was able to figure it out.